# Prevent Add-Content From Displaying String

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

**Executing ***this***:**

```
$String = "Testing123"    
$String | Add-Content -PassThru $Env:WinDir\System32\Test\Test.txt
Pause
```

Returns ***this*** when executed:

```
Testing123
Press Enter to continue...:
```

How do I prevent "Testing123" from showing up while running this script? I am aware of the Pause function, and removing it does not resolve my predicament

Thanks for your time.

Comment: don't use `-PassThru` to suppress output from `Add-Content`. If you want output but would rather see it later, then use `$later = $String | Add-Content -Passthru ...`. Then call `$later` at some future point.

Comment: @AdminOfThings - That was it! Thanks for the awesome explanation - If you want to set your comment as an answer - Ill mark it answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [Add-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7) does not generate any output to the success stream. When the parameter `-PassThru` is added, then the success stream (console output in your case) also receives the added content.

To prevent console output from `Add-Content`, leave off `-PassThru`:

```
$String = "Testing123"    
$String | Add-Content $Env:WinDir\System32\Test\Test.txt
Pause
```

To capture added content to be displayed in a future part of the script, do the following:

```
$String = "Testing123"    
$later = $String | Add-Content -PassThru $Env:WinDir\System32\Test\Test.txt
Pause
# Other code runs here
$later # Outputting added content here
```